# C# HttpWebRequests Proxy error with multithreads

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am multithreading with a threadpool and whenever i try to start the requests i get

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

I don't have the same problem without the proxies tho

This is the code that causes trouble

```
if (ProxyBox.Text != string.Empty)
{
     lock (locker)
     {
         Random rnd = new Random();
         int rndd = rnd.Next(0, int.Parse(ProxyNumber.Text));
         request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxysplit[rndd].ToString());
     }
}
```

Basicaly i want to get a random proxy from the proxysplit array everytime

Any Ideas :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple questions you need to answer before we can help you:

1. Which line is the error occurring on?
2. Is the specified proxy initialized (i.e. not `null`)?
3. Furthermore, is `proxysplit` initialized?

Check what's not initialized and you may also want to generate the random number between 0 and the number of elements in `proxysplit`:

```
if (ProxyBox.Text != string.Empty)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int rndd = rnd.Next(0, proxysplit.Length);
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxysplit[rndd].ToString());
    }
}
```

If you use the the `ProxyNumber` and the resulting integer is outside the range of the `proxysplit` array length, then you may also get an exception while trying to access an element out of range, i.e. `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: i don't have idea on which line the error is occuring on ideas?
for sure there is a proxy in the array i am trying to access
proxysplit is global string[]
tried with proxysplit.Length before, same result

Comment: @FaTaL_ErRoR if you don't know which line the error is occurring on, then how can we help you? I'm sure it tells you which line the exception occurred when the exception gets thrown, so please provide the stack trace. Furthermore, use your debugger to step through the code and see when the exception occurs. **Finally: you didn't answer any of my questions.** Sure there may be **a** proxy in the array, but are **all** the elements of the array initialized? More importantly: is the element which you're trying to access initialized?